I want to code a transmitter with the help of Arduino. I am getting the error given
    // 1 Channel Transmitter | 1 Kanal Verici
    // Input pin A5
    
      #include <SPI.h>
      #include <nRF24L01.h>
      #include <RF24.h>
      const uint64_t pipeOut = 000322;    // NOTE: The same as in the receiver 000322 | Alıcı kodundaki adres ile aynı olmalı
      RF24 radio(9, 10);                          // select CE,CSN pin | CE ve CSN pinlerin seçimi
    
      struct Signal {
      byte aux1;
      byte aux3;
      
    };
      Signal data;
      void ResetData() 
    {
      data.aux1 = 0;                       // Signal lost position | Sinyal kesildiğindeki pozisyon
      data.aux3 = 0;
    }
      void setup()
    {
                                           //Configure the NRF24 module  | NRF24 modül konfigürasyonu
      radio.begin();
      radio.openWritingPipe(pipeOut);
      radio.setChannel(100);
      radio.setAutoAck(false);
      radio.setDataRate(RF24_250KBPS);    // The lowest data rate value for more stable communication  | Daha kararlı iletişim için en düşük veri hızı.
      radio.setPALevel(RF24_PA_MAX);      // Output power is set for maximum |  Çıkış gücü maksimum için ayarlanıyor.
      radio.stopListening();              // Start the radio comunication for Transmitter | Verici için sinyal iletişimini başlatır.
      ResetData();
     
    }
                                          // Joystick center and its borders | Joystick merkez ve sınırları
      int Border_Map(int val, int lower, int middle, int upper, bool reverse)
    {
      val = constrain(val, lower, upper);
      if ( val < middle )
      val = map(val, lower, middle, 0, 128);
      else
      val = map(val, middle, upper, 128, 255);
      return ( reverse ? 255 - val : val );
    }
      void loop()
    {
                                         // Control Stick Calibration for channels  |  Her bir kanal için kumanda Kol Kalibrasyonları 
      data.aux1 = Border_Map( analogRead(A5), 0, 512, 1023, true );   // "true" or "false" for change signal direction | "true" veya "false" sinyal yönünü değiştirir.
      
      data.aux3 = digitalRead(7);
      radio.write(&data, sizeof(Signal));  
    }



You haven't told us, what error you got. Please copy the complete error message (including the information, where in the code the error occurred) into the question-

Even when the specific error you are getting has been made clear to us you'll have another problem. You are transmitting data at loop() speed and this will almost certainly be too fast for the receiver part to process.
